# ASP.Net MVC C# AutoMapper using Where statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

using AutoMapper - is it possible, when mapping a domain to a viewmodel, to use the where statement, to limit what is mapped to the viewmodel, eg. I use the following to map the Offer list to the OfferVM viewmodel:

```
vm.Offers = Mapper.Map<IList<Offer>, IList<OfferVM>>(offers);
```

However, I only want to map items in the list Offer to OfferVM if a property on the Offer is set to true, eg:

```
vm.Offers = Mapper.Map<IList<Offer>, IList<OfferVM>>(offers)
           .Where(x => x.RoomName1s==true);
```

But this gives the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FGBS.ViewModels.OfferVM>'
  to 
'System.Collections.Generic.IList<FGBS.ViewModels.OfferVM>'. 
 An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Thanks for any help.

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the `IEnumerable<OfferVM>` returned by `Where` into `IList<OfferVM>` using `ToList()`

```
 vm.Offers = Mapper.Map<IList<Offer>, IList<OfferVM>>(offers)
       .Where(x => x.RoomName1s==true)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can put the Where clause inside the call to AutoMapper: Mapper.Map...(offers.Where(x => x.RoomName1s == true))

Comment: Thanks @jimmy-bogard - I'm very new to AutoMapper, but can already see benefits from it (many more I'm sure I'll see as I look through posts etc on here) - thank you for producing such a tool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `.ToList()` to convert the IEnumerable to a List.